# JSON.net ambiguous reference bewteen 'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.Func<T, TResult>' and 'System.Func<T, TResult>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

So, I'm trying to include JSON.net library in my Unity project but I have 150+ errors about ambiguous reference between 'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.Func' and 'System.Func.

I downloaded last version of JSON.net (Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.2) and I'm using .NET 4.x.

Shall I fix all errors manually?

Is there a shortcut? Is there a solution?

Comment: you could just use the full type when referencing Func. otherwise, you'll need to update your using statements

Comment: Yes, I know, I'm asking if I need to do it manually for all 150+ errors

Comment: Yes, because as the error states, there is ambiguity, so the compiler doesn't know which Func to use. Just do a solution wide find and replace =]

Comment: Could you not also put 

using Func = Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.Func; or using Func = System.Func;

at the top of the classes that have ambiguous references?

Comment: I can't find any type named `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.Func` in the `Newtonsoft.Json` assembly at all.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/YFAwnk, https://dotnetfiddle.net/JbKGKh and https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Func&type=.  Could you have defined something called `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.Func` somewhere in your code, or in some other DLL you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Newtonsoft JSON build appropriate for Unity3D. [This is the build I use in my shipping game.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2sr31kx6gqqg94p/NewtonsoftJSON.zip?dl=0)

Additionally, place a `link.xml` in your assets folder that contains:

```
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="System">
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.ArrayConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.BooleanConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.ByteConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.CharConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.CollectionConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.ComponentConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.CultureInfoConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.DecimalConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.DoubleConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.ExpandableObjectConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.Int16Converter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.Int64Converter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.NullableConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.SByteConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.SingleConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.StringConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.TimeSpanConverter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.UInt16Converter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.UInt32Converter" preserve="all"/>
        <type fullname="System.ComponentModel.UInt64Converter" preserve="all"/>
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

Finally, for many types, you may have to reference them directly in a script. This will occur most frequently for `List<int[]>` or `List<int?>` sorts of types.